# Why does pdflatex stall when called by NIS Users?

Tags: pdftex, texlive, linux

I ran into a very strange problem recently: I'm administrating Mandriva Linux in a networked setup where users authenticate via NIS. We noticed that pdflatex simply stalls with no error messages and output. All we get is the following:

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011/Mandriva)  
    restricted \write18 enabled.  
    **
```

It doesn't accept any commands or produce any output that we can see. We get the same behavior if we try running it on a file, as in `pdflatex <filename>`
Using a local user (as opposed to an NIS user) account, I was able to compile LaTeX files with no problem, so this seems related to NIS somehow. The weird thing is, we have one NIS user who doesn't face this problem and can compile LaTeX files normally.
Has anybody seen this before? Are there known solutions/workarounds? Is there a way for me to investigate further to help you answer this question?
Thanks

EDIT: My answer below is based on [Martin Schröder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5763/martin-schroder)'s suggestion.

Comment: If this is recurring, try to pipe the contents of the file into the command: `pdflatex < "filename"`. Other than that, if one _can_ then it must be a setup problem. Have you searched for differences in `.profile`, `.bashrc` etc. (dependent on your shell).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I looked at the config files and found nothing related to this.  
Input redirection doesn't work as well.

Comment: Run it with `strace`; it will show you where it hangs.

Comment: Brilliant suggestion! It seems that for some reason, pdflatex is cycling through files on all the users' home directories in search for a certain file, which seems to be what's causing the stall. I'll investigate further when I have time and give you feedback. 
Thanks!

Comment: @MartinSchröder, thanks a lot! Your suggestion helped me pinpoint the problem. Will add details in the answer.

Comment: @JosephR.: You should be able to edit your question and include your findings.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, thanks again for your newbie-friendliness :)

Comment: Presumably this is somehow related to the search syntax in the TeX search libraries. A TEXINPUTS segment of  `/home/david/` would just look in that directory, but a TEXINPUTS segment `/home/david//` specifies that directory and all subdirectories should be recursively searched for file input.

Comment: When you say "it compiles correctly" do you mean that the latex file compiles correctly or just that `pdflatex` runs with no crashes or hangs?

Comment: @AndrewStacey, I mean that it runs with no crashes or hangs and no "undefined control sequence" messages and produces the expected output.  
I was also able to get the correct output through `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf` without resorting to `strace`

Comment: @JosephR. Your real question does not match the title now. I suggest you add your solution to the first question as an answer here and move your second question into a separate posting with a proper title (and delete it here).

Comment: @StephanLehmke Done. Will re-post the second question when I have time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on Martin Schröder's suggestion, I ran `pdflatex` through `strace` and I could pinpoint the problem: the problem was an extra slash in the home directories of users (e.g. `<root_dir>//<user_name>`).

For some reason, this caused LaTeX to search the whole of `<root_dir>` for its binaries, which obviously takes ages. A simple edit of `/etc/passwd` to remove the extra `/` and a re-hash of the NIS domain via

```
cd /var/yp && make
```

did the trick.