# Slow compilation without sudo

Tags: compiling, linux, filesystem-access

With any *.tex file, even with almost empty template, `tex`, `latex`, `pdflatex` commands takes ages to compile it. `strace` shows excessive amount of `stat` calls to all the files in my home directory, which is the cause of slow behaviour. If I run a compilation with `sudo` command all fine and quick as it supposed to be. How can I fix this?

`strace` output consists of many many lines like this:

```
stat("/home/...", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/home/...", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getdents(8, /* 7 entries */, 32768)     = 208
close(8)
```

EDIT: I'm using RHEL 6

`env | grep TEX`

> 

`kpsewhich -a texmf.cnf`

> /usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf

`kpsewhich -var-value=TEXINPUTS`

> .:{/home/username//.texlive2007/texmf-config,/home/username//.texlive2007/texmf-var,/home/username//texmf,/etc/texmf,!!/var/lib/texmf,!!/usr/local/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf}/tex/{kpsewhich,generic,}//

Comment: Do you have the TEXINPUTS variable set?

Comment: You might need to explain a lot more about your system. Sounds like linux. But you never mention anything about your general setup.

Comment: @egreg, uhhh, good one

Comment: Hi there, this sounds like a strange and interesting phenomenon. I'm not an expert, but it seems strange that LaTeX tries to access a lot of files in your home dir. Maybe some TeX paths are set improperly?...

Comment: @egreg No TEXINPUTS isn't set. All my collegues with the same machine and OS doesn't have this problem. Probably I did something weird and unable pinpoint exactly what.

Comment: Can you add the output of the shell commands `env | grep TEX` and `kpsewhich -a texmf.cnf` (as normal user)?

Comment: How did you test that `TEXINPUTS` is not set?

Comment: @egreg OK, Done.

Comment: Just out of interest, is your home dir mounted or sits locally on the computer?

Comment: @daleif Locally, just `/` mounted

Comment: Hmm, very strange. What about `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXINPUTS`

Comment: Hmm, that looks like mine, are you really using texlive 2007?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out guys. Found a [solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75270/why-does-pdflatex-stall-when-called-by-nis-users). It was due to unnecessary `/` in `/etc/passwd` file. Very weird indeed.

Comment: Could it be that finding some of the user files require recursive searching large directories and that for root this is not the case?

Comment: If your `$HOME` ends with a slash, it would explain the double slashes in the values of `$TEXINPUTS`. A double slash means to search subdirectories recursively. This is done up to three times with the HOME directory in the setting of `$TEXINPUTS`, indeed a waste of time.

Comment: You should never, ever compile with `sudo`. Seriously, this is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an error in the path and so not related to TeX/LaTeX